# Open new fragment from another Fragment with ImageView onClick

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to make a menu with imageviews inside  fragment. Everyone got drawer menu, so I want to be different :

I made a OneFragment.java, here is my oncreateview:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
        imageView9 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView5 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageView6 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageView7 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageView8 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

        firstName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imie);


        textView13 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        textView14 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        textView15 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        textView16 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        textView17 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        textView18 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView19);

        final Animation wbijam = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView13.startAnimation(wbijam);
        final Animation wbijam1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView14.startAnimation(wbijam1);
        final Animation wbijam2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView15.startAnimation(wbijam2);
        final Animation wbijam3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView16.startAnimation(wbijam3);
        final Animation wbijam4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView17.startAnimation(wbijam4);
        final Animation wbijam5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView18.startAnimation(wbijam5);






        final Animation animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shak);
        img.startAnimation(animShake);


        final Animation load1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load1);
        imageView9.startAnimation(load1);
        final Animation load2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load2);
        imageView4.startAnimation(load2);
        final Animation load3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load3);
        imageView5.startAnimation(load3);
        final Animation load4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load4);
        imageView6.startAnimation(load4);
        final Animation load5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load5);
        imageView7.startAnimation(load5);
        final Animation load6 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load6);
        imageView8.startAnimation(load6);


        firstName.setText("Hey,"+" " +PreferenceConnector.readString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PreferenceConnector.FIRST_NAME, ""));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
//  return view;
//  ^^^^  error remove it
        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(q);
        // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
        final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(9);
        img.setImageDrawable
                (
                        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                                getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                ));
        return view;
        // ^^^ move it here
    }

        // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...



    protected final static int getResourceID
            (final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx) {
        final int ResourceID =
                ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
                        ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (ResourceID == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                    (
                            "No resource string found with name " + resName
                    );
        } else {
            return ResourceID;
        }

    }

}
```

I want to some one click on

`imageView9 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);`

Will open fragment SecondFragment

Is it possible? 
I tried but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your layout? 
When using a menu to navigate between fragments you keep the menu in the hosting activity and navigate by switching fragments inside that activity, there is no need to put the menu inside one of the fragments.